# Total value using date range in week number and week days format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[Table for Summary Weekly Result
[image: Table for Summary Weekly Result]

I would like to get the summary value between the two dates.... Here's my code

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-02') = 1THEN WD01
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-02') = 2 THEN WD02
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-02') = 3 THEN WD03
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-02') = 4 THEN WD04
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-02') = 5 THEN WD05
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-02') = 6 THEN WD06
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-02') = 7 THEN WD07
END AS VALUE,
CASE
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-28') = 1THEN WD01
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-28') = 2 THEN WD02
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-28') = 3 THEN WD03
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-28') = 4 THEN WD04
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-28') = 5 THEN WD05
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-28') = 6 THEN WD06
  WHEN DATEPART(dw,'2019-02-28') = 7 THEN WD07
END AS VALUE2
FROM SummaryWeeklyTest
WHERE cWeekNum BETWEEN DATEPART(wk,'2019-02-03') AND DATEPART(wk,'2019-02-28')
```

The output should be the sum of highlighted value
[image: The output should be the sum of highlighted value]

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Comment: it should be 99

Answer (score 0):

If you posted your data as txt instead of an image I would produce a complete answer. However as its an image, this is untested. Should give you the idea though.

What I would do is expand the data first, then it becomes easy to do whatever you want:

```
;with days AS (
    select * from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) as t(d)
)
,expanded as (
    select terminal, cyear, cWeekNum, d, 
        case d 
            when 1 then WD01
            when 2 then WD02
            when 3 then WD03
            when 4 then WD04
            when 5 then WD05
            when 6 then WD06
            when 7 then WD07
        end as WD
    from SummaryWeeklytest
    cross join days
)
select sum(WD) from expanded 
where cWeekNum BETWEEN DATEPART(wk,'2019-02-03') AND DATEPART(wk,'2019-02-28')
```